# Licode Export Frames as JPG

Tags: export, jpeg, webrtc, licode

I am trying to build a one to many video publish application based on webrtc and installed [licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/) to my server.

My question is,

Is there any way export frames to a specific folder as jpg, png etc.

Answer (score 0):

don't think they are proving that option yet, but a workaround can be: record the video stream on the server, extract the frames from the recorded file using `ffmpeg`

Comment: I need to export real time frames, not record and export. On the other hand,  recorded file has a huge size so I need another option. I can use ffmpeg or another media server to achieve this problem. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @CnR, technically, recording individual frames might be heavier(if the frame rate is high enough),  another option is using client-side api [getVideoFrame](http://lynckia.com/licode/client-api.html#getVideoFrame)